# Stackdriver Dashboard - Cannot save a dashboard with a custom log-based metric

Tags: charts, google-cloud-platform, dashboard, metric, stackdriver

I have created a log-based metric for some log messages generated by a Dataflow Job. The filter on which this metric is based is behaving correctly (the expected data is displayed in the logs viewer when using this filter).

I am trying to create a dashboard using this user defined log-based metric following the procedure described here https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_based_metrics#creating_a_chart

However, after I select the custom metric from the Metric drop-down, no data is displayed in the preview chart and the Save button is not enabled. Attempting to use the Advanced options does not help either.

Troubleshooting section did not help. Also, I have waited a lot of time after creating the log-based metric and before attempting to create the chart to make sure data will be available (to exclude the situation noted on the page mentioned above: "Note: After you have created your logs-based metric, it will appear in the relevant Stackdriver Monitoring menus but it will have no data. It takes a few minutes for Stackdriver Monitoring to acquire data from Stackdriver Logging.")

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a product manager with Stackdriver.  Dataflow metrics are currently supported in Logging but are currently in alpha in Monitoring, so they'll be coming soon but aren't broadly available yet, since there's the possibility we may make changes as we do more testing.

So, two things based on your question - we've filed a bug since the user experience is kind of confusing between Monitoring and Logging and hope to improve the experience when there is this mismatch of a service supported in one and not the other soon.  We're also testing Dataflow in Stackdriver Monitoring now and expect it to be available more broadly in the near future.  I'll try to post here once Dataflow is fully integrated with Monitoring.  Thanks for using Stackdriver!

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; So it's a bug - that does not appear to be fixed as of the date of this post.